# php/mysql elseif challenges

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying two different queries, both of them are working fine separately but i want a situation where one of them will fall in the elseif statement of PHP or if anyone has a better solution.below is the code for the first and second statement.

first statement

```
$retvval = mysql_query( $sqql);
$sqql = "SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`,
`Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` FROM `doctor_locator`
WHERE state = '$states' AND `name of doctor` LIKE 'Dr%'";
$retvval = mysql_query( $sqql);
if(! $retvval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retvval))
{
 echo "{$row['autoID']}.  "."Name of Doctor: <a href = \"{$row['webpage']}\">{$row['Name of Doctor']} </a><br>"
    ."Email: {$row['Email']} <br>". "Hospital of Practise: {$row['Hospital of Practise']}
    <br>". "State:  {$row['State']} <br>" . "Specialization: {$row['Specialization']} <br> ";
}
```

second statement

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sql);
$sql = "SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`,
`Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` FROM `doctor_locator`
WHERE state = '$states' AND specialization = '$specialize' ";
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql);
 if(! $retval )
 {
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
 {
echo "{$row['autoID']}.  "."Name of Doctor: <a href = \"{$row['webpage']}">{$row['Name of Doctor']} </a><br>"."Email: {$row['Email']} <br>". "Hospital of Practise:{$row['Hospital of Practise']}<br>". "State:  {$row['State']} <br>" . "Specialization: {$row['Specialization']} <br> ";
}
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what exactely you want it to do? Do you want the second statement to run only if the first one fails?

Comment: You should definetly rework your code indentation. Works wonders!

Comment: There is no *elseif* statement in your code. Do you mean `if(! $retvval )`? Just put in `xxx` in the end of your SQL statement to make it fail. Use `mysql_num_rows` to check for how many results are in your query. Though notice that `mysql_` has been deprecated for years and is **no longer supported**. Use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: yes, i want to be able to search for either information

Comment: @h2oooooooo, that is why i need you to provide a solution for me.

Comment: so can you help me do the needful with mysqli or pdo

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`,
`Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` FROM `doctor_locator`
WHERE state = '$states' AND specialization = '$specialize' ";

$sqql = "SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`,
`Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` FROM `doctor_locator`
WHERE state = '$states' AND `name of doctor` LIKE 'Dr%'";

$retval = (mysql_query($sqql) ? mysql_query($sqql) : mysql_query($sql));

if($retval){
      while loop
} 
else { 
      die(); 
}
```

Comment: @anabisystems Instead of the 2 if statements, you make the $retval in a one line if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with PDO:

```
/* Create new connection http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php */
$pdo = new Pdo($connectionString, $user, $pass);
/* Prepare the first query */
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sqql);
/* Without actually executing it, check if there is any error */
if ($statement->errorCode()) {
  /* If so, then prepare the second statement */
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
}

/* Execute it. It will be the first, if it was valid or the second, if the first was not valid. */
$statement->execute();
```